# new Date().getTime() in .NET

Tags: .net, datetime

Basically i want to do the below in .NET but i have no idea how to.

```
var d = new Date().getTime() + " milliseconds since 1970/01/01"
```

Comment: BTW closely related to ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906034/calculating-future-epoch-time-in-c

Comment: The 6 answers I see including the one you accepted uses DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.UtcNow.  I believe this will result in your computation being incorrect by +3,600,000 milliseconds more than half the year in the USA.  This discrepancy may not matter in your particular case but something to be aware of.

Comment: Actually, within local times in the USA, the error will permanently be more than that, as regardless whether DST is active or not, all timezones are far away from GMT/UTC. So, you're right, one *must* use DateTime.UtcNow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd do something like this...

```
var ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970,1,1);
var result = String.Format("{0} milliseconds since 1970/01/01", ts.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about substraction. I couldnt find TotalMilliseconds and was stuck to milliseconds.

Comment: Just want to note that you should also be using UTC times.

Comment: So after 10 years we still use `new DateTime(1970,1,1)`??

Answer (score 9):

I'm not really sure you can get a UNIX date in .NET, but you have DateTime.Now as an equvivalent of new Date() (or new DateTime())

As you got in the comment, it's possible to get a TimeSpan object by doning something in the lines of...

(First answer)

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Adding the final result for the sake of mankind...

```
var d = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1).ToUniversalTime()).TotalMilliseconds + " milliseconds since 1970/01/01";
```

P.S. Where is Jon Skeet with his knowledge of time when we need him :P

Comment: Love the John Skeet battle cry for help :D

Comment: Just want to note that you should also convert to UTC

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an extension method for myself a while back.

It's used like so:

```
 double ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.UnixTicks();
```

Implementation:

```
 public static class ExtensionMethods
 {
  // returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 
                // (useful for converting C# dates to JS dates)
  public static double UnixTicks(this DateTime dt)
  {
   DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
   DateTime d2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
   TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);

   return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your example won't compile.  Perhaps you meant `double ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.UnixTicks();` ?

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction is the way to do it, but all the responses I've seen so far do not correctly adjust for UTC.

You want something like:

```
var ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc); 
var result = String.Format("{0} milliseconds since 1970/01/01", ts.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get there via the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y(v=VS.100).aspx) and [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=VS.100).aspx) structures via [`DateTime.Subtract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=VS.100).aspx), something like:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
ts.TotalMilliseconds; // ...since The Epoch
```

Comment: You should probably use `DateTime.UtcNow` or else convert the time to UTC before doing the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var s = string.format("{0}  milliseconds since 1970/01/01",
           (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("1970/01/01")).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Why hardcode the date as a string?  Also, you really should be doing the calculation in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I was fooling around and saw this example, but ended up modifying it to this:

```
var st = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToFileTimeUtc();
            var t = (DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTimeUtc());
            Debug.WriteLine(t - st);
```

Will give a number like 16202########

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan dtNow = new TimeSpan();
dtNow = dt.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
Console.WriteLine(dtNow.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Bit long-winded in comparison to others, but it works.

Comment: You should be using `DateTime.UtcNow` or else call `dt.ToUniversalTime()`.  Also, you have two constructor calls that are superfluous.