# Serialize DateTime to least number of characters for storage

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a limit of 255 characters in a field of a persistent store. In those 255 characters I would like to store the maximum number of Date and time values which could then be deserialized successfully in an application. Would converting them to an `int` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788883/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-an-int) be my only option?

Comment: How much precision do you need to store? (seconds? milliseconds? nanoseconds? time zone?) Does the string need to be printable?

Comment: @SLaks Forgot to mention.. upto minutes only no timezone info required. Non-printable is fine as well.

Comment: What range do you want to support?

Comment: Do you want to be able to encode the year 9999?

Comment: Do you need to encode only the 21st century so far? That only takes four bits for a year.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes 21st Century only, don't think this app would endure 87 more years. Not to forget the world may end Dec 21 this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert each DateTime into an integer value in as few bytes as possible (probably 5 – 8, depending on what you want to preserve).
If you only need to store minutes, 3 bytes will cover 31 years and 4 bytes will cover 8,166 years.

Pack those bytes into a byte array, then convert that byte array to Base64.  This will store one date every 6 characters.

Alternatively, pick a non-Unicode encoding and convert the byte array directly to a string This will store one date every 4 non-printable printable characters.

Comment: @Jeroen: I wrote that before he mentioned non-printability.

Comment: @SLaks I just posted a code sample as per your recommendation !!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @SLaks, Is this how you suggested I go about it (if I did want printable chars):

```
        [Test]
        public void DateTimeTest()
        {
            var dateTime = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12, 12, 12, 0);
            int intDateTime = Int32.Parse(dateTime.ToString("yymmddHHMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            byte[] bytesDateTime = BitConverter.GetBytes(intDateTime);
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesDateTime);

            Debug.WriteLine(base64);    // Prints fIA/SA==

            byte[] newBytesDateTime = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            int newIntDateTime = BitConverter.ToInt32(newBytesDateTime, 0);
            var newDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(newIntDateTime.ToString(), "yymmddHHMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

            Assert.AreEqual( dateTime, newDateTime );
        }
```

Comment: Instead of using string parsing, you should store the number of minutes since some fixed base date.