# How to Convert DateTime to Int, it is reading 'Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'?

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got a for loop using a `DateTime`, I'm trying to add points to a chart by summing the data; however, when running the loop I get this error:

> InvalidCastException was unhandled: Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to
>   'Int32'.

Here is the code in the for loop I am trying:

```
List<Series> dataSeries = chartDailyCost.Series.ToList();
for (DateTime i = Convert.ToDateTime("00:00"); 
              i <= (Convert.ToDateTime("23:45")); 
              i = i.AddMinutes(15))
{
    double sum = 0d;

    //for every series in the chart collection sum the yvalues at the specified 
    foreach (Series s in dataSeries)
    {
        //This is the line I am getting the error for
        sum += s.Points[Convert.ToInt32(i)].YValues[0];
    }
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    //Add a new yvalue to the datapoint for the summed series's

    //And I will get an error in this one as well
    dp.XValue = dataSeries[0].Points[Convert.ToInt32(i)].XValue;

    dp.YValues[0] = sum;
    sumSeries.Points.Add(dp);
}
```

Comment: Let me know what do you expect to be the integer value of "23:45" (as a datetime)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788883/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-an-int take a look at this. I don't know if it's what you want.

Comment: The question is, how your Points array is indexed. Is it in 15 minute increments? Then I'd use an int for i with 1 increment for every 15 minutes. Or is it seconds? minutes? hours? There are accessors for all kinds of data inside the DateTime struct.

Comment: It is in 15 minute increments from 00:00 up to 23:45

Answer (score 1):

You never actually need a `DateTime`, instead what you should do is loop over an `int`, like so:

```
const int intervalMinutes = 15;
const int numIntervals = 24 * (60/intervalMinutes);
for(int i = 0; i < numIntervals; ++i)
{
    double sum = 0d;

    //for every series in the chart collection sum the yvalues at the specified 
    foreach (Series s in dataSeries)
    {
        sum += s.Points[i].YValues[0];
    }
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    //Add a new yvalue to the datapoint for the summed series's

    //And I will get an error in this one as well
    dp.XValue = dataSeries[0].Points[i].XValue;

    dp.YValues[0] = sum;
    sumSeries.Points.Add(dp);
}
```

If you do need a `DateTime` inside of your loop, create it like so:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().AddMinutes(intervalMinutes * i);
```

Comment: Hey cheers for that, it does make sense, but when I am searching through each data series for the numintervals, how do I go about that?            I missed out the line of code, seen in the first line of the edit, and this: List<Series> dataSeries = chartDailyCost.Series.ToList();      cheers for any more help!