# Convert Date from user control into Integer in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert `dtFrom` into `integer` in ASP.Net C#

```
<%@ Register Src="~/DatePicker.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="DatePicker" %>
<uc1:DatePicker runat="server" ID="dtFrom" />
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788883/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-an-int

Comment: At what point you want to do it? In the handler code or what? How exactly you want date to be represented as a number? ddmmyyyy? or what/

Comment: You should be clearer, as we can't know the format you want to get. Maybe a int with yyyymmdd? DateTime.Ticks?

Comment: @Andrey I want it in yyyymmdd Format

Comment: @Brinda then look into linked question - it has all you need