# Get Epoch in C# for GMT

Tags: c#

I need to get number of milliseconds from the epoch in GMT.

Can I use this for the GMT part:

`DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`

What about the number of milliseconds since the epoch?

Comment: Not too much own research, eh? ;) possible duplicate of [Calculating Future Epoch Time in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906034/calculating-future-epoch-time-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should give you a TimeZone agnostic answer.

```
TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
double ms = t.TotalMilliseconds ;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that second `DateTime` be local time, not UTC?

Comment: Experimentation suggests that your code above is correct. Seeing that it's a bit counter-intuitive (one would think `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)` would be local time and the calculation would be off), it would be useful to say *why* this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as easily as below in newer .NET versions;

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```

Refer [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=net-7.0).